# bumblebee xb3 driver

Tags: ros, camera1394

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am new to the bumblebee camera. I tried using the triclops and pgrstereo library to grab images but was not successful in getting the center image. Is there a driver available? Or any example that can grab all the three images from triclops?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66375/bumblebee-xb3-driver/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am Joan Pau, author of the camera1394stereo package, now maintained by a collegue.
This package was created to handle binocular cameras, namely bumblebee2 but it should work with any other IIDC camera supported by libdc1394 producing binocular stereo images using the usual way.

From the system point of view, a firewire IIDC stereo camera is seen as a single device (not two or three), it has a unique GID (device identifier on the firewire bus) and a unique set of parameters (frame rate, video mode, ...). Stereo cameras usually use 'smartly' some video modes to transmit 2 or 3 images at a time (one for each camera).

- For 2 images they use a video mode with 16 bit depth (2 images x 8 bits/pixel) or with 32 bit depth (2 images x 16 bits/pixel).
- For 3 images they use a video mode with 24 bit depth (3 images x 8 bits/pixel).

Depending on the camera each single image is either mono or has color information encoded in Bayer pattern indicated by the manufacturer.
For the Bumblebee XB3 this is described in section Stereo Image Formats here:

http://www.ptgrey.com/support/downloads/documents/Bumblebee%20XB3%20Getting%20Started%20Manual.pdf

The camera1394stereo driver is just a copy of the camera1394 one, but with the added functionality to deinterleave the stereo image into two separated images and publish them to two different topics (left and right) with the corresponding camera info topic. So in your case it won't work for a stereo camera with 3 images.

However, you can use the following approach. Use a camera1394 nodelet to grab and publish the 24 bit depth images from the bumblebeeXB3 as if it was a mono camera. Here you can set the frame rate and the other camera parameters. And write a simple nodelet that subscribes to an image topic and deinterlaces the input images, publishing 3 output images to the corresponding output image topics (left, center and right) each one with the corresponding camera info. This should be quite easy to implement (even though it would add some overhead, for which I would not worry if using nodelets because images are not copied). For the camera info part the CameraInfoManager already does the job, you just have to use three instances (one for each output topic):

http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_info_manager

Actually, it might be even useful to have this included in the image_proc chain: a stereo_split or stereo_decompose nodelet, wich subscribes to an input image topic and decomposes it according to the following parameters:

- number of output images,
- their pixel bit depth,
- the stereo mode (how pixels from each camera are merged in the stereo image)

This same nodelet should provide the camera info topics for each of the output images, the camera info of the original stereo image should be simply ignored.

Sorry for the long response.

---

Originally posted by [joanpau](https://answers.ros.org/users/893/joanpau/) with karma: 191 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2013-07-04**:
HI, Thank you for the detailed response. When using the pgr_examples, I had problems exactly with interlacing the input image given by libdc. Will try your suggestion next week and will keep this thread updated.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-05**:
Thanks for explaining, @joanpau, your suggestion is a good one. I agree that the overhead of an extra nodelet would not be prohibitive. Once it is working, we could add it to image_common or to camera1394, if that seems appropriate. Bumblebee questions come up regularly.

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2013-07-15**:
Thanks guys, grabbing the images was more easy than I thought. Just need to publish in format7_mode3 with format color rgb8 and iso speed 800

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use my XB3 on ROS.
Are there any updates about this?

Or the best way is to use the Linux SDK to implement a new ROS node for xb3?

---

Originally posted by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) with karma: 287 on 2016-01-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since I only need to use two cameras,  Is it possible to use bumblebee xb2 ros node with my trinocular system?
I just need to use outer cameras and not the central one.

Thank you

---

Originally posted by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) with karma: 287 on 2016-01-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1